# List box items go outside from listbox in window application

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I am facing a UI issue in list box. The issue is very inconsistent sometimes it comes at first button and sometimes it occurs after many clicks or when I use scroll bar of listbox. I do not understand how and from where it is coming.

I am sorry to say that I can not define the issue but I am attaching a image of this issue to illustrate my problem:

[image]

I have done some code for selecting all items and deselect all items at button clicks. The code is given below:

```
private void btnSelectAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lstSelectRows.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;
            for (int i = 0; i < lstSelectRows.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                lstSelectRows.SetSelected(i, true);
            }
        }

private void btnSelectNone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.lstSelectRows.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
```

Comment: That's a new one.  Does this happen on any other computer?

Comment: I have checked on other computer.I think it is working fine at other computer.

Comment: See [Listbox display problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/78abf225-561a-42ed-ae83-e1f694b361f8/listbox-display-problem?forum=vbgeneral)

Comment: @Amit: was the below answer correct? It would be nice to accept it, if so.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid visual glitches like this, make sure pause drawing while the items are being updated.

Simply call [`ListBox.BeginUpdate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.beginupdate.aspx) before you update the items, then call [`ListBox.EndUpdate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.endupdate.aspx) when you are done.

```
private void btnSelectAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lstSelectRows.BeginUpdate();
            lstSelectRows.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;
            for (int i = 0; i < lstSelectRows.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                lstSelectRows.SetSelected(i, true);
            }
            lstSelectRows.EndUpdate();
        }

private void btnSelectNone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lstSelectRows.BeginUpdate();
            this.lstSelectRows.SelectedIndex = -1;
            lstSelectRows.EndUpdate();
        }
```